# Move additional information tab from WooCommerce to second position

Tags: php, wordpress, tabs, woocommerce

I'm trying to find my way to move the tab for additional information from WooCommerce, from the first position to the one before the reviews. At the moment the Additional information tab is the first tab, and so far, the bes i found is how to make it disappear with the following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_remove_product_tabs', 98 );

function woo_remove_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

unset( $tabs['description'] );        // Remove the description tab
unset( $tabs['reviews'] );            // Remove the reviews tab
// unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );      // Remove the additional information tab

return $tabs;

}
```

And I can not manage to think a way of accomplishing what i'm doing, as my logic tells me that in order to tell the tab to be moved to the one before the last tab (the reviews tab) there must be some kind of order such as first, second, third, etc...

Comment: `$tabs` is just an array. So the first index in the array will be the first tab, and so forth. You need to rebuild the array in the order that you want.

Comment: Ok, I found a small code, that Im trying to manage, and it definetely does something, but it just works for woocommerce native tabs, and in my case, I have a few EXTRA tabs added with a plugin. The problem is I dont know how to identify/declare those extra tabs in the code. Would you please guide me on how or where to look to know how to declare each tab in this function?

Comment: add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'reordered_tabs', 98 );
function reordered_tabs( $tabs ) {
    $tabs['cherry_wc_video']['priority'] = 5; 
    $tabs['description']['priority'] = 10; 
    $tabs['reviews']['priority'] = 15;
 
    return $tabs;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working that piece of code, but not quite sure of why does it actually works, so it would be good if some expert can explain. But here is the piece of code I used in my personal case:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'reordered_tabs', 98 );
function reordered_tabs( $tabs ) {
    $tabs['additional_information']['priority'] = 10; 
    $tabs['detailed-information']['priority'] = 5; 
    $tabs['reviews']['priority'] = 15;

    return $tabs;
}
```

The additional_information and the detailed-information, i took them from my web by inspecting the element and inputting the value of the

```
<a href="#tab-additional_information" data-toggle="tab">Additional Information</a>
```

I just removed the "#tab-" and it worked.

Hope someone can clarify a bit more and it can help someone else.

Comment: Your new tabs need a callback function. Take a look at LoicTheAztec's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39965478/383847) on how to create custom tabs.